# Communication between javascript and its hosting java or c++ application

Tags: java, javascript, c++

I'm trying to find out if there is a standard or recommended way to communicate from javascript to the application which embeds a browser widget, and vice versa.   The hosting application may be written in either java or c++ and may run on Windows and Unix platforms, but the javascript would be shared across both clients.

So far I've read about:

- window.external  (This seems to be IE specific, so it wouldn't work on Unix.)
- LiveConnect (This seems to be java and mozilla specific, so it wouldn't work for IE or c++ based applications.)
- SWT's Browser widget has some of this capability, but this would be a java-only solution..

What other options are out there?

Thanks!
    Shyam

Comment: I think the [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is a good solution. It is a standard (RFC 6455), supported by many modern browsers and has a c++ implementation(s), for instance, [WebSocket++](http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp).

Comment: I think I might have been a bit misleading,  what I'm trying to find is a way for javascript to invoke methods in the hosting application.   I think WebSocket is for bi-directional communication across the network....I'm just looking for a standard way to communicate within the single application....from javascript to java/c++ and vice versa.

Comment: You say the backend application can be written in java or c++ does it also serve the http? Otherwise how does the client application or browser widget get the data from the backend application?

Having looked at your comments to @megabyte1024 it sounds like you're trying to use the back end application as a headless browser. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Hi booyaa,  well the java/c++ client would embed a Browser widget to present the UI in HTML/javascript format.  The java/c++ client would also query data from a server to be presented based on user interation in the HTML/javascript.  I hope this makes sense.  For example, a tree node in the HTML/javascript might be expanded to get children, the expansion would have to invoke a java/c++ method in the client to retrieve the list of children from the server.

Answer (score 0):

We have a VB6 application that hosts Microsoft's [WebBrowser object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (IE). We've used a simple URL intercept mechanism to facilitate communication between the browser and the hosting application. Since the browser control has a [before navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface, we can pull out the URL and examine it for commands and either cancel the navigation event (since it was meant for the hosting app) or let it pass through (since it is a normal URL).

We used something like `app://commandName?arg1=val&arg2=val` in our Javascript or HTML link tags.

Then in the BeforeNavigate event from the browser, we check the url for `app://` if we get that, we know the browser is sending the parent application a message.

Simple but effective (for our needs anyway).

**EDIT**

Should also mention that most embedded browsers also have mechanisms to manipulate the DOM. That in mind you should be able to extract information (HTML nodes) and inject information at will.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has the [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) API that makes it possible to send data to, and retrieve data from a server. The use of this API with messages formatted in XML or JSON is designated [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

AJAX can be used to implement the example you gave, of a tree node in the HTML/javascript that retrieves the list of children from the server when it is expanded.
Note that when using AJAX, the server may be written in any language (C, Java, Python, Ruby, etc).

I suggest you to read about AJAX. After you get a good understanding of AJAX you can read a little bit about [web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service). **web service** is a method of communication of 2 applications developed in arbitrary programming languages through the WEB.